# Firebase Notifications not being delivered if sent other than firebase console

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a really strange issue, the notifications sent from the Firebase Console are being delivered properly so it means the project is configured and certificates are correct, but when I send notification from the app it doesn't work. I am using the following method to send notifications.

```
func sendPushNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String, Type: String) {

        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let paramString: [String : Any] =
            [
                "message" :[
                    "to" : token,
                    "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                    "data" : ["notification_type": Type]
                ],
                "to" : token
            ]

        print(paramString)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=AAAApQ9EAjg:XXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = data {
                    if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                    }
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()



    }
```

I have also tried sending through **curl** with the following method

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ussaidiqbal
 * Date: 2020-02-17
 * Time: 19:45
 */

$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = "eMIK6wGOTUUutqp62vEIr-:XXXXXX";
$serverKey = 'AIzaSyCJFUydXXXXXXXXXX';
$title = "Title";
$body = "Body of the message";
$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,

    "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
//Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//Close request
if ($response === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I also have tried to send through **PostMan** using the following payload

```
{
    "notification":{
        "title": "XXXXX",
        "body": "XXXXX"
    },
  "to": "XXXXXXX"
}
```

This is the response of the request

```
{
    "multicast_id": 36126XXXXXXXX,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1581960379105057~~~~~~~~~~"
        }
    ]
}
```

None of the above method seems to be working, What am I doing wrong?
I have tried both the **Legacy server key** and **Server key** but no luck. Has anyone ever faced such an issue?

Comment: I think your problem is ```setValue```, you should use ```addValue```. SetValue will replace all values!

Comment: I have tried addValue as well

Comment: Is your "to" Tokens correct? Did you use the FirebaseMessage token? not APN Token? Try that with Postman, what you get as a response or status code?

Comment: `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) ` I have used the token generated here

Comment: But you don't send the PushNoti to the same device!? Notification will not word if the App was 1. Open, 2. Simulator (Simulator could be changed maybe), 3. If you send your self a Push. 

Try that with Postman. Is the best way

Comment: I am sending a push notification from simulator to actual device, I have tried php postman and http request through app nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending a lot of time I figured it out and it's all working normally. So if anyone else facing this issue they can solve by opening your `AppDelegate.swift` file, find a function `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and replace with the following

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
         Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
```

After doing this all seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct NotificationStruct: Codable {
    var notification: NotificationBodyStruct?
    var to: String?
    var time_to_live = 60000
}

struct NotificationBodyStruct: Codable {
    var title: String?
    var text: String?
    var sound: String?
}    



func sendNotificationtoken: String, name: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    do {
        let noti = NotificationStruct(notification: NotificationBodyStruct(title: name, text: text, sound: "default"), to: "\(token)", time_to_live: 6000)
        let body = try JSONEncoder().encode(noti)

        makeConnection(body: body) { (success) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("sendNotification \(error.localizedDescription)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}    



private func makeConnection(body: Data, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send") else {
            completion(false)
            return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "key=A**YOUR_KEY**A"]
    request.httpBody = body

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error NotificationHelper ", error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            print("httpResponse error NotificationHelper ")
            completion(false)
            return
        }


        guard httpResponse.statusCode  < 500 else {
            print("Error NotificationHelper < 500 \(httpResponse)", response ?? "" )
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        guard (httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode <= 299) else {
            print("error NotificationHelper  >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode <= 299 \(httpResponse)", response ?? "" )
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        guard let _ = data  else {
            print("Problem with Data NotificationHelper ")
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        completion(true)
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: I returns true but same no message delivered!

Answer (score 0):

I think also that your paramString has the wrong properties. Try that:

```
        let paramString: [String : Any] = [
            "to" : token,
            "notification" : ["title" : title, "text" : body],
            "time_to_live" : 60000,
            "sound" : "default"
        ]
```